# separate a column by a string [special case where the string is not always present]

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
col1 <- c("test-1", "test-2","test")
col2 <- c(1,2,3)
df <- data.frame(col1,col2)
```

I would to like separate col1 and my data look like this

```
check1 check2 col2 
test      1    1
test      2    2 
test     NA    3
```

a function like this would not work

```
separate(df, col1, c("check1,check2"),"-")
```

any idea why?

Comment: Try `separate(df, col1, c("check1", "check2"),"[-]")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `fill = 'right'` to fill NAs in case of missing values and prevent displaying any warnings

```r
col1 <- c("test-1", "test-2","test")
col2 <- c(1,2,3)
df <- data.frame(col1,col2)
library(tidyverse)
df %>% separate(col1, into = c('checkA', 'checkB'), sep = '-', fill = 'right')
#>   checkA checkB col2
#> 1   test      1    1
#> 2   test      2    2
#> 3   test   <NA>    3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the OP's issue, instead of creating a vector of column names, there is a syntax issue i.e. `c("check1,check2")` is a single element and it should be
`c("check1","check2")`

```
separate(df, col1, c("check1","check2"),"-")
```